# Second-order Trotter error involving an unbounded Hamiltonian

Tags: operators, mathematical-physics, hamiltonian, approximations, time-evolution

I have an Hamiltonian of this form:

\begin{equation}
H = \frac{p^2}{2m} + V(x),
\end{equation}
I would like to approximate the time evolution for a time $\tau$ of a known initial Gaussian state $|\Psi_0 \rangle$ with known moments of $x$ and $p$ with (let $\hbar = 1$)

\begin{equation}
e^{- \mathrm{i} H \tau} \approx L_2(t) =  e^{- \mathrm{i} p^2/(2m) \tau/2} e^{- \mathrm{i} V(x) \tau}   e^{- \mathrm{i} p^2/(2m) \tau/2}.
\end{equation}

In https://arxiv.org/abs/1912.08854 (Eq. (150)), I find as an estimation of the "Trotter error" following formula:

\begin{equation}
|| L_2(t) - e^{- \mathrm{i} H \tau}|| \le \frac{\tau^3}{12} || [V(x), [V(x), p^2/(2m) ]] || +  \frac{\tau^3}{24} || [p^2/(2m), [p^2/(2m), V(x) ]] ||,
\end{equation}

where $||.||$ is the "operator norm" or "spectral norm".
However, How can I calculate $|| x^2 ||$ or $ || p x ||$ if these operators are unbounded?

My question is: Is there another way of estimating the Trotter error involving the initial state vector and its moments of $x$ and $p$ ?

Edit: I would also be very happy with any other method quantifying the validity of the above approximation in case there exists any.